# Renew certificates by running script as cronjob

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I need to renew my Let's encrypt certificates, which I do like this:

```
$ sudo docker stop nginx
$ sudo docker run -it --rm -p 443:443 --name certbot -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest renew
$ sudo docker start nginx
```

I have run these commands regulary, so I would like to create a cronjob. So far I created this file:

```
$ sudo nano /opt/letsencrypt.sh
```

with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo docker stop nginx
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 443:443 --name certbot -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest renew
sudo docker start nginx
```

To add this file to the cronjobs I did:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/crontab

5 8 * * 6   root /opt/letsencrypt.sh
```

But nothing is happening at all. No error, no action. What am I doing wrong?

Would be great if the job could be logged, so I can see when it was running...

Comment: Be sure your script has execution premission (chmod +x /opt/letsencrypt.sh ). Did you try to run the script from your prompt? Does it work? In /var/log/syslog (or othr system log accordng your distro) you can find if crontab ran your script. You can redirect stdout / stderr to a file to understand in details what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made your script executable?

If not, try `chmod +x /opt/letsencrypt.sh`

Comment: By simply entering `/opt/letsencrypt.sh`. If you get a `permission denied` error, it is likely that your script isn't executable (yet).

Comment: Ok, manual running is working. Hope the same thing is running by cronjob now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use `-it` when you run `docker run` inside `crontab`:

Wrong:

```
0 3 * * * docker run -it --rm --name certbot ...
```

Correct:

```
0 3 * * * docker run --rm --name certbot ...
```

You can also log your output to a log file:

```
0 3 * * * docker run --rm --name certbot ... > /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

This logs both, the std-out `[1]>` and the errors `2>`to that file.